# MySQL Server keep shutting down

Tags: server, shutdown, mysql, wordpress

mysql server is keep shutting down, i am using DigitalOcean 512 MB Memory and 20GB Disk.
**I am running WordPress and iRedMail**.
Here are my Error Logs:

```
Version: '5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port$
150202 18:28:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of $
150202 18:28:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150202 18:28:47 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150202 18:28:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150202 18:28:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150202 18:28:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150202 18:28:47 [ERROR] Aborting

150202 18:28:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Here is my /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
    #
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16K
max_allowed_packet  = 16K
table_cache = 1
sort_buffer_size = 16K
read_buffer_size = 16K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1K
net_buffer_length = 1K
thread_stack        = 16K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Set the query cache low
query_cache_limit = 1048576
query_cache_size = 1048576
query_cache_type = 1
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16K

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash  
# faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16K
sort_buffer_size = 16K
[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 16K
sort_buffer_size = 16K
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout


#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Is 512MB memory and 20GB Data is not enough for WordPress, if it is then what am i doing wrong?
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114746/mysqld-service-stops-once-a-day-on-ec2-server) (or this [Database Administrators one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/intermittent-mysql-crashes-with-error-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-t)), it deals with the exact same situtation. The amount of RAM seems too small for MySQL, you will need to configure your DB server and possible your webserver too.

Also, if you do not have a swap partition, you should have one, if it is possible.

Another piece of advice: you would have been better off asking this question on another member ot the Stack Exchange sites, as this have nothing to do with Ubuntu.